# fuelphp -Undefined variable

Tags: php, fuelphp

I have book model view controller and I have library controller and view .
The view folder has `index.php` and `view.php` .
My question in my index.php i get following error:

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: books
```

Here is the code in my **index.php** file:

```
 <h2>Library</h2>
<?php foreach ($books as $books): ?>
<h3><?php echo Html::anchor('library/view/'.$book->id, $book->title)?></h3>
<p><?php echo $book->description?> </p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Rename $books to $book in the condition of foreach-loop? Like this: <?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two errors there. One is that `$books` array is not initialized (hence the warning), other is that your `foreach()` is wrong. Replace this:

```
<?php foreach ($books as $books): ?>
```

with

```
<?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>
```

But you still need to find your missing `$books` array

Comment: yes i did in my controller thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Change the line :`<?php foreach ($books as $books): ?>`

to

```
<?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>
```